# Joining two tables when there is a not matching record exist

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to use 1 sql statement to produce the result I want.
I got 2 tables named , order and customers,  and tried to use a query like this

```
select a.*, b.customers_name 
from order a, customers b 
where a.customers_id=b.customers_id   
order by b.customers_name;
```

My problem is there is a fake customers_id in order table, if customers_id=0 then
customers_name='In House' which does not exist in cumstomers table. 
It's been used like this way before I joined this company so I can not modify the table at all.

Is there way to display the result?
All order from order table with customers_name and if customers_id=0 (<= no match record in customers table) then customers_name='In House') and output should be ordered by customers_name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select a.*,
        COALESCE(b.customers_name, 'In House') as customers_name
from
    order a LEFT JOIN customers b ON a.customers_id=b.customers_id
order by
    customers_name;
```

or

```
select a.*,
         CASE
           WHEN a.customers_id = 0 THEN 'In House'
           WHEN b.customers_name IS NULL THEN 'Unknown'
           ELSE b.customers_name
         END as customers_name
from
    order a LEFT JOIN customers b ON a.customers_id=b.customers_id
order by
    customers_name;
```

Either way, use an explicit JOIN for clarity.

The first one adds "in house" for *any* missing customers, the second one deals with missing customers by adding Unknown if customerid is not 0

Comment: If left join is used, how can I add some more condition for order table such as order_date >= 5/01/2013?

Comment: oh, I got it, Thank you for your quick responce

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use a [LEFT JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/left-join-optimization.html) for this.

```
select a.*, b.customers_name
from order a
left join customers b
on a.customers_id = b.customers_id
order by b.customers_name;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select a.*, IFNULL(b.customers_name, 'In House')
from order a
LEFT JOIN customers b ON a.customers_id=b.customers_id   
order by b.customers_name;
```

Heh we all got the same answers here...

Answer (score 0):

One option:

```
select a.*, case when a.customers_id=0 then 'In House' else b.customers_name end as customers_name
from order a
left join customers b on b.customers_id=a.customers_id;
```

BTW I suggest you use the "join" syntax. It's a lot easier to read then putting your join conditions in the "where" clause.

Answer (score 0):

This approach uses `UNION` to add the "customer 0" row during the query, then it does an `INNER JOIN`. Use it only if a `LEFT JOIN` doesn't work. Your `order` table obviously doesn't have a foreign-key relationship to `customers` (else you wouldn't be able to have a `customer_id` of `0`), so a `LEFT JOIN` could pick up some garbage; you'll have to be the judge of that.

```
select a.*, b.customers_name
from order a
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT customers_id, customers_name
  FROM customers
  UNION SELECT 0, 'In House') b ON a.customers_id=b.customers_id
order by b.customers_name;
```